# Is my current flow annotations correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, superposition, nodal-analysis

I have this circuit given and we're asked to get the contribution of the 75V source to iR using superposition.

The yellow and red line in the picture are my assumed current flow. However, I couldn't construct a nodal equation that would make sense from it. Are my annotations correct?

Also, I want to simplify the resistances on the left side of 75k ohms and I get **16.7k ohms**. Is this correct?

[image: Given Circuit]

Comment: Use the schematic editor and do a better job of explaining the circumstances surrounding the question. I have some thoughts. But I'm also somewhat confused, too. I don't see the "next two questions" for example, which would help me follow what's being asked if they were included. But without them, I have too many questions, myself.

Comment: Welcome to EE!  Please show your work so far.  The direction of the current will not affect the structure of the problem, only the signs.  If you assume the wrong direction, then that value will simply end up negative.